# Save method not working

Tags: apex, upsert

I have a vf page. I'm unable to add a save method to it. I have a few fields on visualforce page. I am able to write a save method for it. Here my code so far.

```
public class NewAndExistingController {
public Subscription_Detail__c tempUsers { get; private set; }
public List<Subscription_Detail__c> sd=new List<Subscription_Detail__c>();
public list<Subscription_Detail__c> singlegroup= new List<Subscription_Detail__c>();
public NewAndExistingController() {
List<Subscription_Detail__c> tempUsers=[SELECT name,
                                                  Customer__r.id,
                                                  Customer__r.Name, 
                                                  Chanto_Order__c, 
                                                  Chanto_Shipment__c,
                                                  Delivery_Confirmation__c,
                                                  New_Order__c,
                                                  New_Shipment__c FROM Subscription_Detail__c  WHERE 
                                                  Customer__r.id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];

}

public PageReference save() {
        for(Integer i=0; i<tempUsers.size() ; i++){
           singlegroup.add(new Subscription_Detail__c(tempUsers[i])); 
    }
return singlegroup ; 
    try {
        upsert(tempUsers);
    } catch(System.DMLException e) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        return null;
    }
    //  After Save, navigate to the default view page:

}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your code even compile?  What do you mean by **not working**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating through and then returning "singlegroup" before doing any DML - so the DML won't be seen, and since you aren't returning a PageReference (or a null) the VF is probably not doing much either.